# Matlab MemMapFile for a three dimensional matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, memory, matrix, hibernate-mapping

I have a three dimensional matrix called "Shanto" of size (232,232,3052).

I want to memory map this, and am using the following command:

```
fileID = fopen('Shanto.dat','w');

fwrite(fileID, Shanto, 'single');

fclose(fileID) 

m = memmapfile('Shanto.dat')
```

However, when I try to access m.Data, I am given a 657083392 x 1 uint8 array.

How do I make it such that I can retain the (232,232,3052) shape of the original matrix?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When loading your `.dat` file you can specify the shape/format (the default is uint8 actually).
You also need to specify the correct data format using fwrite:

```
fileID = fopen('Shanto.dat','w');

fwrite(fileID, Shanto, 'uint8'); %// Instead of 'single' as before.

fclose(fileID) 

m = memmapfile('Shanto.dat','Format',{'uint8',[232 232 3052],'MyFancyName'})
```

You can then access the corresponding 3D array using `m.Data.MyFancyName`

More info [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memmapfile.html)

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I get this error:

A subscripting operation on the Data field attempted to create a
comma-separated list. The memmapfile class does not support the use
of comma-separated lists when subscripting.

Any suggestions for this? 

Thanks man

Ben

Comment: Oops I forgot to mention that when using fwrite you also need to specify the uint8 format. I edited my answer; that should work now.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help Benoit!

Much appreciated. 

Solved it!

Comment: Awesome then! Glad to help :)